# Проблемы с наследованием в Java

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток всем. Хочу поднять свой уровень и научится делать кастомные вьюхи. Думал сначала взять `TabLayout` и просто переопределить метод `onDraw` допустим, но тут же столкнулся с проблемой(скорее всего нехваткой знаний). В общем проблема в том что после наследования и переопределения метода `onDraw` в моем классе(MyTabLayout), я хочу что бы все остальные методы супер класса(TabLayout) остались как были, так что в чем мой косяк и как это сделать? 
П.С. Простите за глупый вопрос.

```
 */
public class MyTabLeyout extends TableLayout {

private int mIndicatorLeft = -1;

private int mIndicatorRight = -1;

private int mSelectedIndicatorHeight;

private final Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint;

private static final Pools.Pool<TabLayout.Tab> sTabPool = new Pools.SynchronizedPool<>(16);

private final ArrayList<TabLayout.Tab> mTabs = new ArrayList<>();

public MyTabLeyout(Context context, Paint mSelectedIndicatorPaint) {
    super(context);
    this.mSelectedIndicatorPaint = new Paint();
}
public int getTabCount() {
    return mTabs.size();
}




private void setIndicatorPosition(int left, int right) {
    if (left != mIndicatorLeft || right != mIndicatorRight) {
        // If the indicator's left/right has changed, invalidate
        mIndicatorLeft = left;
        mIndicatorRight = right;
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
}
void setSelectedIndicatorColor(int color) {

    if (mSelectedIndicatorPaint.getColor() != color) {
        mSelectedIndicatorPaint.setColor(color);
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
}
void setSelectedIndicatorHeight(int height) {
    if (mSelectedIndicatorHeight != height) {
        mSelectedIndicatorHeight = height;
        ViewCompat.postInvalidateOnAnimation(this);
    }
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.draw(canvas);

    // Thick colored underline below the current selection
    if (mIndicatorLeft >= 0 && mIndicatorRight > mIndicatorLeft) {
        canvas.drawCircle(mIndicatorLeft,getHeight() - mSelectedIndicatorHeight,10,mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
        // canvas.drawRect(mIndicatorLeft, getHeight() - mSelectedIndicatorHeight,
        //      mIndicatorRight, getHeight(), mSelectedIndicatorPaint);
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: Ну... Так переопределите только нужный метод и всё... Остальное удалите...

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, так после если я с другого класса обращаюсь к методам из моего созданного класса их не "видно" ```final MyTabLeyout tabLayout = (MyTabLeyout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("VIDEOS"));``` в том случае методы `addTab` && `newTab` не определяет

Comment: Не знаю в чём у вас проблема. Я вот только что расширил класс от TabLeyout, переопределив конструктор минимальный + onDraw. И все перечисленные вами методы как и ожидалось вполне себе видны.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, re: переопределив конструктор минимальный, это что ты имеешь в виду???

Comment: Это я имею в виду конструктор с одним аргументом - контекстом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы просто опечатались. Вы хотели расширить `TabLayout`, а расширили `TableLayout`.

Будьте внимательны)

Comment: А ещё в имени вашего класса опечатались. Код писать лучше не ночью)))

Comment: боже, аахахха. Щас сам с себя в голосину сижу смеюсь..все таки ночью иногда лучше поспать)) Спасибо большое)